# MySQL MAX value with 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I'm trying to update SQL table with results of students contest. For that contest I've 2 tables: participants (name, class, school, etc.) and results (participant_id, results and subject). Now I need to give each participant a status - 1st place, 2nd place or 3d place based on their results.

The tricky part is the rules of that contest. Each participant must get this status in their respective school and class. So I must have winners in each school and each class. It's quite simple to update table with 2nd and 3d place as they counted as result >= 50 and result < 50. But the 1st place must be the highest score in this school and in this class.

I tried a lot of combinations with MAX() statement but with no success. No matter what I try I can't make it show maximum value based on 2 conditions (max in school, max in class). I need something like =MAXIFS() in Excel, but don't know how to do it in SQL.

UPD. Examples

Table `participants`

```
| id | name | class | school |
------------------------------
| 01 | John |  10   |  312   |
| 02 | Jack |  10   |  312   |
| 03 | Mary |  11   |  144   |
| 04 | Dany |  11   |  312   |
| 05 | Mark |  7    |  144   |
```

Table `results`

```
| id | participant_id | subject | score |
-----------------------------------------
| 01 |        03      |    4    |   55  |
| 02 |        01      |    4    |   75  |
| 03 |        04      |    4    |   60  |
| 04 |        05      |    4    |   45  |
| 05 |        02      |    4    |   90  |
```

And the result I need must look like this:

```
| id | participant_id | subject | score |   status  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 01 |        03      |    4    |   55  | 1st place |
| 02 |        01      |    4    |   75  | 2nd place |
| 03 |        04      |    4    |   60  | 3rd place |
| 04 |        05      |    4    |   45  | 3rd place |
| 05 |        02      |    4    |   90  | 1st place |
```

Basically, 1st place is MAX in each school and class, 2nd is less than MAX and >= 50 and 3rd is just less than 50.

Can't show everything I tried because it's all variations of the same query. Something like that:

```
SELECT
    id, participant_id, subject, score,
    (CASE
       WHEN score >= 50 THEN '2nd place'
       WHEN score < 50 THEN '3rd place'
       WHEN score = MAX(score) THEN '1st place' 
    END) AS 'status'
FROM results 
INNER JOIN participants ON results.participant_id = participants.id 
GROUP BY participant_id
```

I've also tried with subqueries, but it's obviously not helping - different subqueries even give different number of rows or resulting 'status' doesn't match the score and other information.

Comment: Could you create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your input data and what result do you want to get for that example data ?

Comment: Please provide table schemas, sample data and desired results

Comment: and show what you tried that didn't work

Comment: Why does the participants table appear in the query?

Comment: Please learn how to use `GROUP BY`.  Your query is invalid.

Comment: Please look is it answer you question: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=388f8b80e98eb78e9970f3b236fb5c70&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: Mary, Dany and Mark on 1st place because them single participants from theirs classes. Only school 312 class 10 have more then one participants so Jack on 1st, and John on 2nd place in their class

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev sorry for the last comment, I was wrong at first. It did the trick, thank you so much! Could you post it as full answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: If we exclude class from competition and it will based only on school we will get next: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=971583b0fe8ff1ca9a03fc41684f5214&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: I posted my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next query can be used as solution:

```
SELECT 
    participants.*,
    results.*,
    (CASE
     WHEN score = max_score THEN '1st place' 
       WHEN score >= 50 THEN '2nd place'
       WHEN score < 50 THEN '3rd place'
       
    END) AS 'status'
FROM participants
JOIN results ON results.participant_id = participants.id 
JOIN (
  SELECT
    class, school, max(score) max_score
  FROM results 
  INNER JOIN participants ON results.participant_id = participants.id 
  GROUP BY class, school
) max_results ON 
    max_results.class = participants.class AND
    max_results.school = participants.school;
```

And here the fiddle: [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=388f8b80e98eb78e9970f3b236fb5c70&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)